# Смена локализации в приложении

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот использую код для смены локализации(с сохранением языка), но методы locale и updateConfiguration устарели. Можно ли использовать этот код как окончательный, то есть будет ли он всегда работать на всех версиях андроида? Если надо подправить, подправьте код пожалуйста..

```
private void changeLang(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);

    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


    saveLocale(lang);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

private void saveLocale(String lang) {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Изменить язык с перезагрузкой приложения:

```
changeLang("en");
```

Comment: Посмотрите какие методы сделаны на замену устаревлих да и все.

Comment: Для уверенности, что будет работать везде, делают ветвление по уровню API, в котором метод объявлен устаревшим. API-level и чем нужно заменить обычно указано в документации. Для примера можете глянуть код здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077

Comment: @woesss, Не могу к этому ответу прикрутить SharedPreferences, attachBaseContext(Context newBase) срабатывает до того, как читается локаль из SharedPreferences..

Comment: Получите её из преференсов непосредственно в самом методе, например.

Comment: Где бы пример нормальный найти, с SharedPreferences и attachBaseContext, весь гугл перерыл, ничего толкового..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так (Kotlin, но общий смысл должен быть понятен):

```
    val myLocale = Locale(lang)
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale)
    val config = android.content.res.Configuration()
    config.setLocale(myLocale)
    baseContext.createConfigurationContext(config)
```